How to fetch username in an tableau extension
I am trying to create a tableau extension for which I need the username… can anyone help me how to extract the username dynamically from tableau to my extension can anyone help me with this solution
when i try to fetch the username it shows undefined..
const getSheetDataForUsername = (worksheets, index) => {
    console.log(worksheets);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      const summaryOptions = {
        maxRows: 0, // Max rows to return. Use 0 to return all rows
        ignoreAliases: false,
        ignoreSelection: false,
        includeAllColumns: true,
        summary: true,
        tableauDataTranspose: true,
      };
      if (index < worksheets.length) {
        // const sheetName = worksheets;
        // const sheetName = worksheets[index].name;
        const sheetName = worksheets[index].Worksheet;
        console.log("Sheetname " + sheetName);
        getSheetData(sheetName, summaryOptions, worksheets)
          .then(function (sheetData) {
            const dataRow = sheetData && sheetData.length ? sheetData[0] : {};
            if (dataRow.hasOwnProperty("AsUser")) {
              UserName = dataRow.AsUser;
              console.log("Found AsUser wb -->: ", UserName);
              setUsername(UserName);
              resolve(UserName);
              alert(username);
            } else {
              console.log("here");
              resolve(getSheetDataForUsername(worksheets, ++index));
            }
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error getting data for sheet: ", error);
            resolve(UserName);
          });
      } else {
        resolve(UserName);
      }
    });
  };
`

